# Access IIF to SQL Statement convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have access query and I am converting it to TSQL(SQL Server).  I'm looking for the equivalent to the Access IIF statement in SQL Server.

Below is the statement I am trying to convert;

```
IIF(((ISNULL([Total], 0) * [SellThrough])/100)/IIF(ISNULL([NoOfStores], 0) = 0, 1, ISNULL([NoOfStores], 0))/IIF(ISNULL([FPWeeksOfSelling], 0) =
                 0, 1, ISNULL([FPWeeksOfSelling], 0)) < 0.1, 0, ((ISNULL([Total], 0) * [SellThrough])/100)/IIF(ISNULL([NoOfStores], 0) = 
                 0, 1, ISNULL([NoOfStores], 0))/IIF(ISNULL([FPWeeksOfSelling], 0) = 0, 1, ISNULL([FPWeeksOfSelling], 0)))
```

I tried to use Case but I am not able to write it. Could you please convert the above query in CASE statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite ugly but give this a try:

```
CASE WHEN ((ISNULL([Total], 0) * [SellThrough]) / 100) / 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL([NoOfStores], 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE ISNULL([NoOfStores], 0) END 
    / CASE WHEN ISNULL([FPWeeksOfSelling], 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE ISNULL([FPWeeksOfSelling], 0) END < 0.1 THEN  0 ELSE 
((ISNULL([Total], 0) * [SellThrough]) / 100) / CASE WHEN ISNULL([NoOfStores], 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE ISNULL([NoOfStores], 0) END / CASE WHEN ISNULL([FPWeeksOfSelling], 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE ISNULL([FPWeeksOfSelling], 0) END END
```

Answer (score 0):

how to change this Query in sql server

```
    ("select IIF(MAX(bill_bno) IS NULL,1,MAX(bill_bno)+1) from rec_all 
where rw=0 and iif(month(bill_date)>=1 AND month(bill_date)=3,
year(bill_date)-1, year(bill_date))=" & IIf(Month(Date) >= 1 AND Month(Date) <= 3, Year(Date) - 1, Year(Date)))
```